# JQGRID: Save row after change value of a calculated cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm stucked with this problem. I have a grid with a subgrid. When I edit a cell value of a column, my function goes through all subgrid rows and get's all values from that column and changes the value of a column of the parent row that opens this subgrid.

Here is my functions code:

```
function reloadGrid(rowid, dataResponse) {
    $('#' + rowid).parent().trigger('reloadGrid');
}

function calculate(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var id = $.jgrid.stripPref("_" + $.jgrid.stripPref(subGrid.getGridParam('idPrefix'), rowid), rowid);
    id = $.jgrid.stripPref("s_", id);
    var ids = subGrid.getDataIDs();
    var result = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        result = result + parseFloat(subGrid.getCell(ids[i], 'value'));
    }
    grid.setCell(id, 'Total', result);
    reloadGrid(rowid);
}
```

I tried to use this after `setCell`, but It seems to work only if you edited a cell, not if it's value changed automatically.

```
grid.saveRow(id, function(){alert("It works!");}, 'foo/edit.html?identifier=' + grid.getCell(id, 'identifier'));
```

What I want is to save the parent row that opens the subgrid after the cell has changed his value.

Thanks in advance.

PS: `grid` and `subGrid` variables are defined at the beginning of the JS. I think no need to explain what contains these variables...

**UPDATE**

Already solved, thanks anyway to all.

What I do is getting the `row_id` of the parent grid with `$.jgrid.stripRef(...)` in my current edited row. Using a function, every time I save my edited subgrid data I call that function that get all values from `import` column in my subgrid and sum them. After I get the total value, just have to do `grid.editCell(row_id, 'total', sumResult)`, `var data = grid.getRowData(row_id)` and do an `ajax` call to the same `URL` where I send my edited data as if I do it via form:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/edit.html?identifier=' + data.identifier,
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: null,
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorText) {
               alert("HTTP Status code: " + jqXHR.status + "\nStatus text: "
               + status + "\nError: " + errorText);
    }
});
```

That's what I wanted to do. I dont know if it is clear, but I have the solution. If someone don't understand something, just ask. **;)**

Comment: Sorry, but it's very difficult to understand what you do. You wrote about "calculated cell", but not included definition of the column. You wrote about saving of row, but not speak about any editing mode. Indirectly one can see that you use `saveRow` from inline editing, although the most scenarios don't required that you calls `saveRow` directly. It's absolutely unclear *why* one need make any modifications of subgrids on modification of the main grid. Typically subgrid will be loaded from the server on every expending of subgrid, so no modifications of subgrid are needed.

Comment: When I edit a row I use `afterSave` property at `editOptions`, after an `inlineEdit` is done and it calls to `calculate` function. I need to do that, to save a calculated field from parent grid into the database. I have to import a Basic Desktop application into a Java Web application and they did it in that way. Grid -> Click to expand row and loads a subgrid -> If you change something and press save, it sends data to server, recalculates total prize of subgrid and put that value at parent row `'Total'` column. What I need is that when it recalculates, save the row where it has been modified.

Comment: @Oleg Forgot to say at the beginning that I use `afterSave` at the subgrid and the function is called after editing a row from subgrid.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to answer on one more question with multiple "UPDATED" parts and 45 comments. You should imagine that you speak with somebody who knows jQuery and jqGrid and you explain short and clear the problem which you have. **So you should modify your question to make it full clear. You can include pictures, demos (in jsfiddle for example) or any other**. The question should be clear enough that no additional questions in comments are needed.

Comment: @Oleg Okay, thanks anyway. Then I will ask only one thing. Can I add a function on `afterSave` property at subgrid to save a row from parent Grid?

Comment: My problem that I have to guess permanently what you mean. If you write for example: "add a function on `afterSave` property at subgrid" you mean probably setting `aftersavefunc` callback of `editParams` property of `inlineNav` or `aftersavefunc` callback of `addParams.addRowParams` of `inlineNav`. In the case callback defined in subgrid will be not called in case of saving the main grid. But I can't understand **why** it could be needed. If you set common `aftersavefunc` callback in `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` then the callback will be called on any saving of the row.

Comment: My problem is that I understand indirectly that you have some common data or some relation between the main grid and subgrid, but I have absolute no idea what you do. To be able to help you I need first understand what you do. I don't understand *why* it's so difficult to explain clear *what you do*. Why you don't want just to edit the text of your question and explain what you do? Sorry.